# Issue with using await and request-promise

Tags: node.js

As a background, I have a nodeJs controller that goes out and downloads images from a 3 party Website. To do this, I need a Key and a temp token which I have. Problem is sometimes token is expired before I download image in which case my download will be a 0 byte size jpg. So instead of having a bunch of 0 byte files I want to check after download what size the file is and if t is 0 then delete.
I am using the request-promise to await the completion of writing file to system but it seems not to work. It looks to me the download is completed but the file has not be saved to drive via the pipe. If I go and put a sleeper of a few ms all works fine. So how can I make sure if a file has been downloaded and saved (piped) to hard drive before I go check its size ?

Here is a snippet of my current code

```
const getImages = async (key, exk, size, pic_count, apn, mls ) => {
    let i;
    let fullPath = "";
    let fileName;
    const newPath = "./images/" + folderBySize(size);
    if (!fs.existsSync(newPath)) {fse.ensureDirSync(newPath); }
    for (i = 0; i < pic_count; i++) {
        fileName = uuid() + ".jpg";

        console.log("File Name : " + fileName);
        fullPath = newPath + fileName;

        console.log("Checking File: " + fullPath);

        const response = await rp.get(imageUrl + key + "&TableID=50&Type=1&Size=" + size + "&exk=" + exk + "&Number=" + i).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fullPath));

        //await resolveAfter2Seconds(1)
        await getFilesizeInBytes(fullPath);

        console.log("done");
        }
  }

  const getFilesizeInBytes = async (filename) => {
    try {
    const stats = fs.statSync(filename);
    const fileSizeInBytes = stats.size;

    console.log("File: " + filename + " Size: " + fileSizeInBytes);
    if (fileSizeInBytes === 0) {

    console.log("Delete File: " + filename );
    fs.unlink( filename, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    })
    }
    } catch (error) {
       console.log(error);
    }
  };

  getImages(316868841, "2897223e91f137e03714ec2bbce6212c", 2 , 5, 12345678, "OC123456" );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`await` only does something useful when you await a promise that is exactly tied to the asynchronous operation you're trying to wait for.  You have a number of places in your code where, what you are awaiting is not a promise so it isn't waiting for the underlying asynchronous operation to complete.  That messes up the timing in your code.

First a little background...

An `async` function allows you to use `await` on operations that return a promise.  But, an `async` function contains no magic juju about asynchronous operations that aren't promise based.  So, when you do `fs.unlink()` in `getFilesizeInBytes()`, that's just a random asynchronous operation that the function `getFilesizeInBytes()` does not wait for.  Similarly, there is no return value in `getFilesizeInBytes()` so the promise that is returned from that `async` function has an `undefined` resolved value.  So, when you do `await getFilesizeInBytes(fullPath)`, you're going to get an `undefined` value.

So, right now your `getFilesizeInBytes()` function returns before the `fs.unlink()` operation is done and it returns a promise that resolves to `undefined`.

To do proper asynchronous design, I'd suggest you change `getFilesizeInBytes()` to this:

```
const fsp = require("fs").promises;

const getFilesizeInBytes = async (filename) => {
    const stats = await fsp.stat(filename);
    const fileSizeInBytes = stats.size;

    console.log("File: " + filename + " Size: " + fileSizeInBytes);
    if (fileSizeInBytes === 0) {
        console.log("Delete File: " + filename );
        await fsp.unlink(filename);
    }
    return fileSizeInBytes;
};
```

This uses the fs module promises API built into newer versions of node.js and will now properly wait (before resolving the returned promise) until all the operations in the function are done and will also return the fileSizeInBytes.

---

In addition, when you do this:

```
const response = await rp.get(imageUrl + key + "&TableID=50&Type=1&Size=" + size + "&exk=" + exk + "&Number=" + i).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fullPath));
```

You are essentially doing this:

```
const response = await rp.get(...).pipe(...);
```

But, `.pipe()` does not return a promise.  It returns the stream.  So, you're awaiting a stream which doesn't do anything useful.  Thus, your `await` doesn't wait for everything to finish downloading and saving to disk.

The request-promise library contains specifically recommends against using `.pipe()` with the request-promise library.  It says to use the regular request library for `.pipe()`.  To solve your particular issue, you may have to either promisify `.pipe()` yourself or just use the proper events on the stream to know when it's done and when you should continue with the rest of your code.

---

I'm not sure what the best way is to promisify the end of a stream.  I may need to do some more looking into that.  Here's one way that monitors the `close` and `error` events on the write stream to resolve/reject a promise when the stream is done.  It doesn't look like the new `fs.promises` interface has yet covered this type of promise use with streams.

```
const request = require('request');

const getImages = async (key, exk, size, pic_count, apn, mls ) => {
    let i;
    let fullPath = "";
    let fileName;
    const newPath = "./images/" + folderBySize(size);
    if (!fs.existsSync(newPath)) {fse.ensureDirSync(newPath); }
    for (i = 0; i < pic_count; i++) {
        fileName = uuid() + ".jpg";

        console.log("File Name : " + fileName);
        fullPath = newPath + fileName;

        console.log("Checking File: " + fullPath);

        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(fullPath);
            writestream.on('close', resolve).on('error', reject);
            request.get(imageUrl + key + "&TableID=50&Type=1&Size=" + size + "&exk=" + exk + "&Number=" + i)
              .on('error', reject).pipe(writeStream);

        });


        //await resolveAfter2Seconds(1)
        await getFilesizeInBytes(fullPath);

        console.log("done");
     }
}
```

You probably also want to convert `fs.existsSync()` and `fse.ensureDirSync()` to asynchronous operations.  For race conditions reasons, `fs.existsSync()` is generally discouraged in any kind of multi-user or multi-threaded or clustered system.

---

FYI, here's a reusable wrapper function that "promisifies" the `.pipe()` operation for `request.get()`.

```
// wrap a request.get().pipe() stream so you know when it's done
// pass the same args to this that you pass to request except no completion callback
// this monitors the read stream for errors and the write stream you pass to `.pipe()` for completion and errors
//
// Sample usage:
//     requestPipePromise(someUrl).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(myFile)).then(function() {
//         console.log(".pipe() is done successfully");
//     }).catch(function(e) {
//         // got some error in either the request or the pipe
//         console.log(e);
//     })
// 

const request = require('request');

function requestPipePromise(...args) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        let r = request.get(...args);
        r.on('error', reject);
        r.pipeOrig = r.pipe;
        // replacement .pipe() function that hooks the writestream to monitor it for completion/errors
        r.pipe = function(writeStream) {
            writeStream.on('error', reject).on('close', resolve);
            r.pipeOrig(writeStream);
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: Thats not the issue here. The issue is that the Request promise downloads the file but it seems it has not been completly written to disk while we are already getFilesizeInBytes function. It fails after 2 downloads if i dont have a sleep before i call it. It seems the await lets go after download is complete not the pipe part

Comment: @MisterniceGuy - For that part of the issue, do you know if `rp.get().pipe()` returns a promise that represents when the piping is all done?  All I can find in the request-promise doc is a recommendation NOT to use `.pipe()` with it.  As I say in my answer, `await` only works if you're awaiting a promise that is properly tied to the thing you're trying to wait for.

Comment: @MisterniceGuy - Since it's recommended not to use `.pipe()` with `request-promise` and I can't find any code inside of the `request-promise` library that deals with `.pipe()`, I suspect it's still just returning the stream (like the request library does) so you're trying to `await` the stream which doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: So how can i do this to wait for stream to complete, save the stream to local file before i check on the size. It would be even better to check the size of the stream before i save, that way i wouldnt have to check on file size and delete 0 byte files

Comment: @MisterniceGuy - I'm working on a specific recommendation for a good solution.  Give me a bit of time.

Comment: @MisterniceGuy - OK, I came up with an option for manually promisifying the end of the write stream, so you can await it inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Yes that works, so it was not the await of the request but the actual pipe which sometimes wasn’t completed when I checked for size

Comment: @MisterniceGuy - When you do `await rp.get().pipe()`, what you're awaiting is the returned result from `.pipe()` which isn't a promise (it's the stream).  And, probably neither the request nor the pipe were done yet, but most importantly the `.pipe()` wasn't done yet so the output file wasn't finished being written yet.

Comment: The stream was done the pipe not. And the await was only for the stream. Do you know if there is a good way to check the size of stream before it is piped ? I am trying to figure out a way to check if 0 before I even write to disk vs checking after write. This might be normally no issue but when you do batches of 10000 images at a time anything helps

Comment: @MisterniceGuy - Show me a fully built URL for one of these items you're calling `rp.get()` on and I can take a look.  If you could share one that has data and one that does not, that would be best.