# Why is fs.js returning [object Object] and shutting down my bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm working on a discord bot that does a variety of things. It keeps randomly crashing and I tracked down the source of the error. What it does is it downloads images sent to it in a discord private message, hashes them and sets their name to the hash to make sure no duplicates exist. This is not the most efficient way to do so but it works.

Here's my code (it's a bit messy)

```
message.attachments.forEach(url => {
    if (!message.author.bot) {
        function getDate() {
            let d = new Date().getTime();
            return d;
        }
        tempdate = new getDate();
        ext = path.extname(url.url);
        request.get(url).on(`error`, console.error).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./temp/Img-${tempdate}${ext}`));
        hash = sha256(`./temp/Img-${tempdate}${ext}`);
        if (fs.existsSync(`./attachments/Img-${hash}${ext}`)) {
            request.get(url).on(`error`, console.error).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./attachments/Img-${hash}${ext}`));
            console.log(`Error: Duplicate File`)
        }
        fs.createWriteStream(`./attachments/Img-${hash}${ext}`);
        console.log(`Wrote Hashed File.`)
        fs.unlinkSync(`./temp/Img-${tempdate}${ext}`)
    }
})
```

Every once in a while, however it returns this:

```
fs.js:1061
  return binding.unlink(pathModule._makeLong(path));
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink 'C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\testbot\temp\Img-[object Object].png'
    at Object.fs.unlinkSync (fs.js:1061:18)
    at Client.client.on.message (C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\testbot\yes.js:48:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Client.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\xxxxx\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\xxxxx\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\xxxxx\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\xxxxx\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\xxxxx\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
```

I assume I did something wrong here. I can't find any answers online

Comment: Make all your variables local with `var` or `let`.

Comment: Something else is probably using the global variable `hash`.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing synchronous and asynchronous code.

The `.pipe()` is absolutely asynchronous, yet you're trying to assume that it's done immediately.  You can't reliably program this way.

You need to listen for an event to know when the `.pipe()` is done before you can proceed with the rest of the processing.

And, as soon as you make it event driven, your `.forEach()` will run ahead with multiple iterations trying to run at the same time and then the fact that your variables aren't declared locally inside the loop will cause variable conflicts.

Also, what is this line of code doing all by itself:

```
fs.createWriteStream(`./attachments/Img-${hash}${ext}`);
```

You create a write stream, but don't even keep track of it.  That will just leak a file handle.

---

As for solutions, it really requires a significant rewrite.  I've answered a similar question here [Issue with request and .pipe()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57486165/issue-with-using-await-and-request-promise/57486295#57486295).  In that answer, I created a promise wrapper for `.pipe()` which would then let you use `await` to sequence a pipe operation.  I'd probably use that solution in rewriting this code.

Comment: Thanks. I'll make it async.